# Регулярное выражение для поиска непоследовательных дубликатов слов

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle

```
([[a-zа-я|А-Я]+)([[:space:]]+)\1
```

Данное регулярное выражение позволяет найти в тексте дубликаты слов, которые следует друг за другом. Например:
"Что **мне мне** делать".
Но каким должно быть регулярное выражение, если я хочу найти непоследовательно повторяющиеся слова?

Comment: А как должен выглядеть результат? Вы можете дать пример?

Comment: Я предложил решение, которое находит как последовательные, так и непоследовательные повторяющиеся слова. Если подразумевалось другое, прошу меня поправить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться следующим выражением:

```
SELECT * FROM regexTest WHERE 
   REGEXP_LIKE(
      test, 
      '([^_a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]|^)([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+)[^_a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ].*\2',
      'i')
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/GwMPl5/1).

**Подробности**

- `([^_a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]|^)` - Захватываемая подмаска №1 (в регулярках Oracle нет поддержки незахватываемых групп): любой 1 символ, отличный от английских и русских букв, цифр и знака подчёркивания (`[^_a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]`) или (`|`) начало строки (`^`)
- `([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+)` - Захватываемая подмаска №2: 1 и более английских или русских букв
- `[^_a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]` - любой 1 символ, отличный от английских и русских букв, цифр и знака подчёркования
- `.*` - 0 и более любых символов, отличных от знака перевода на новую строку (если использовать модификатор `n` (т.е. третий аргумент должен быть `'in'`), можно найти повторяющиеся слова на разных строчках строки)
- `\2` - обратная ссылка на значение захватываемой подмаски №2.

См. [SQL-демо](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9386/6):

```
CREATE TABLE regexTest(
test varchar2(50));

INSERT INTO regexTest VALUES ('Что мне тут мне делать');
INSERT INTO regexTest VALUES ('Что мне мне делать');
INSERT INTO regexTest VALUES ('Что тут мне делать');
INSERT INTO regexTest VALUES ('Что делать? Дела?');
INSERT INTO regexTest VALUES ('Дела,дела...');
INSERT INTO regexTest VALUES ('Ничего-ничего, так себе...');
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM regexTest WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(test, '([^_a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ]|^)([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+)[^_a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ].*\2')
```

Результат:

```
TEST
Что мне тут мне делать
Что мне мне делать
Дела,дела...
Ничего-ничего, так себе...
```

Флаг `'i'` позволяет находить повторяющиеся слова в разных регистрах. Если его убрать, будут найдены только 2 результата:

```
Что мне тут мне делать
Что мне мне делать
```

Answer (score 5):

Так найти только первое совпадение (см. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/sNoCg8/1)):

```
select regexp_substr (str, pattern) match
from (
    select 'не как то что мне не мне что' str, '(^|\s)(\w+)\s.*\S+.*\s\2(\s|$)' pattern 
    from dual
);

match               
---------------------
не как то что мне не
```

Если нужны все дубликаты, то самое простое, двигаться вперёд по словам (граница первого слова будет всегда начало строки - `^`:

```
select regexp_substr (substr(str, nextWordPos), pattern) match from (
    select str, pattern, regexp_instr (str, '\w+', 1, level) nextWordPos from (
        select 'не как то что мне не мне что' str, '^(\w+)\s.*\S+.*\s\1(\s|$)' pattern 
        from dual
        )
    connect by level < regexp_count (str, '\w+') -1
)
where regexp_substr (substr(str, nextWordPos), pattern) is not null
;

match                                           
-------------------------------------------------
не как то что мне не                             
что мне не мне что                               
мне не мне
```

---

Движок регулярных выражений *Oracle* имеет целый ряд ограничений, например, отсутствие границ слова (`\b`), нет поддержки незахватываемых групп, поиска вокруг и т.д.
Если всё же надо обойти эти ограничения, то можно реализовать свою функцию, например, на Java.
Пример ([демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/vR7VzF/1/)):

```
select column_value match 
from table (getMatches (
    'не как то что мне не мне что', 
    '\b([\p{L}\p{N}_]+)\b(?=.*(\b\1\b))'
));
```

Вывод:

```
match                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
-----------------------------------------
не at 0/2 has duplicate at 18/20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
что at 10/13 has duplicate at 25/28                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
мне at 14/17 has duplicate at 21/24
```

Сама функция:

```
create or replace type matchesType is table of varchar2(256);
/
create or replace and compile java source named "Utils" as
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Match {
    public static java.sql.Array getMatches (String input, String pattern) throws java.sql.SQLException {
        return OraUtils.toSqlArray ("matchesType", getMatchesArray (input, pattern));
    }
    private static String[] getMatchesArray (String input, String pattern) {
        List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile (pattern).matcher (input);
        while (m.find()) {
            matches.add (m.group()+" at "+m.start()+"/"+m.end ()+" has duplicate at "+m.start(2)+"/"+m.end(2));
        }
        return matches.toArray (new String[0]);
    }
}    
public class OraUtils {    
    static java.sql.Array toSqlArray (String typeName, Object elements) throws java.sql.SQLException {
        oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver ora = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver();
        oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection oraConn = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) ora.defaultConnection();
        java.sql.Array arr = oraConn.createARRAY(typeName.toUpperCase(), elements);
        return arr;
    }
};
/
create or replace function getMatches (s varchar2, p varchar2) return matchesType deterministic as
language java name 'Match.getMatches (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) return java.sql.Array';
/
```

Начиная с версии Java 7 (БД 12.1, 12.2) можно пользоваться `\w+` для юникодов с флагом `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`. Ожидать той же производительности, как и у функций внутреннего движка, не следует.